# Handling the http cookie from GWT module

Tags: java, gwt, cookies, browser

I have a small confusion about Cookies, whenever the user is logging in we create cookies and adding to the response header.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("sessionId", "232hghjghghgh"); // http cookie.
cookie.setVersion(1);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(1000);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

I think the above will be setting into the browser cache and we can get it from the browser cookies.

In our GWT module we already have an existing implementation like

```
Cookies.getCookie("sessionId"); // Cookies are from GWT
```

We are able to get the cookie using above line without using anywhere Cookies.setCookie() method.

Is that because of above line response.addCookie(cookie).

Could any body tell me, is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your first example is using a `javax.servlet.http.Cookie`, and this happens on the server side. The latter is purely GWT (i.e. client side) and returns `java.lang.String` (i.e. the String value of the cookie). But of course both are conceptually the same and setting one on the server will make the other show up on the client.